# Can data-* attribute contain HTML tags?

Tags: html

I.E. `<img src="world.jpg" data-title="Hello World!<br/>What gives?"/>`

Comment: Everything's data in this world.

Comment: Did you check it? What is the output?

Answer (score 32):

As far as I understand the guidelines, it is basically valid, but it's better to use HTML entities.

From the [HTML 4 reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/charset.html):

> You should also escape & within attribute values since entity references are allowed within cdata attribute values. In addition, you should escape > as > to avoid problems with older user agents that incorrectly perceive this as the end of a tag when coming across this character in quoted attribute values.

From the [HTML 5 reference:](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attributes)

> Except where otherwise specified, attributes on HTML elements may have any string value, including the empty string. Except where explicitly stated, there is no restriction on what text can be specified in such attributes.

So the best thing to do, as @tdammers already says, is to escape these characters (quoting the W3C reference)

- `&amp;` to represent the `&` sign.
- `&lt;` to represent the `<` sign.
- `&gt;` to represent the   `>` sign.
- `&quot;` to represent the `"` mark.

and decoding them from their entity values if they are to be used as HTML.

Comment: Note that the OP is asking about data- attributes, i.e. an HTML5 feature, so answers should be based on the HTML5 draft, not on HTML4. But your advice is essentially correct, it's valid to do so.

Comment: But how about if I have to format data in data- attribute, so I can hook some css, or plain HTML formating? Can I wrap data- string in <p> tags so I can use <br/> tag?

Comment: @Alan you can basically put anything you want into a data attribute - I don't see the point of adding CSS into it, though. Would it not make more sense to add that to the main stylesheet?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have like this structure "content: attr(data-title)", where "data-title" is text, and I have to put <br/> tags in data-title string in my html.

Comment: @Alan so do it, ideally encoding the `<br/>` into `&lt;br/&gt;` (and decoding it again wherever you want to use it)

Comment: @Pekka웃, that's exactly what I do, but it won't decode, it won't render to break tag. I'm not even shure what to do. Maybe http://jsfiddle.net/7tf64tk9/ would help.

Comment: @Alan ah, I see. That may not work out - you're using CSS to import the data, so you'll have no chance to decode the HTML entities. You'd have to use JavaScript to decode (which is a shame, since your tooltip works without JS at the moment)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks, I was afraid that I have to use JS in my CSS only tooltip.

Answer (score 13):

Providing you're serving it as text/html, then yes it's valid.

Note that not only is it possible to include markup inside attributes, but the HTML5 srcdoc attribute on the iframe element positively encourages it. The HTML5 draft says:

> In the HTML syntax, authors need only
>   remember to use U+0022 QUOTATION MARK
>   characters (") to wrap the attribute
>   contents and then to escape all U+0022
>   QUOTATION MARK (") and U+0026
>   AMPERSAND (&) characters, ....

Note, that when served with an XML content type (e.g. application/xhtml+xml), it is not valid, or even well-formed.

Comment: +1 this is spot on because these are the only two characters that one *must* escape. This was the section I was looking for

Answer (score 7):

I'd say yes, as in it's still valid HTML5. Older browsers (which ones?) may not parse correctly.

Section *3.2.4.1 Attributes* of the current HTML5 draft says this:

> Except where otherwise specified, attributes on HTML elements may have any string value, including the empty string. **Except where explicitly stated, there is no restriction on what text can be specified in such attributes.**

HTML tags inside attributes also validates at http://html5.validator.nu

Comment: +1 for HTML 5 reference - obviously though, you'll have to escape your quote character if in a inline attribute (`data-xyz="..."` must not contain an unescaped `"`)

Comment: Of course! I don't know if Javascript converts &quot; into " when you access the attribute through the DOM, though.

Comment: yeah, I'm not sure either, OP will have to try out what works in his context

Comment: Certainly. Entities are converted into their values when parsed.

Comment: IE 7 doesn't like IT! :(

Answer (score -2):

No. That would be invalid - HTML does not allow < or > inside attributes.

`<img src="world.jpg" data-title="Hello World!&lt;br/&gt;What gives?"/>` would be valid, but it would display the <br/> literally, not as a newline.