# JavaScript window.open onclick ('url')

Tags: javascript

I just figured out that I needed this link to be inside a `data` tag, because the `data` uses " ", and I can't include both.

Is this possible to do with `document.getElementById("id")`?

Or do I need another script for this? As you can tell I'm not the best with JavaScripts yet. Hope to learn a thing or two.

```
<a href="chat" onclick="return popitup('chat')">Pop</a>

<script>
function popitup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,height=600,width=330');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}
</script>


<a href="#" class="emotes show-pop btn btn-default top" data-title="Settings" data-content="<a href="chat" onclick="return popitup('chat')">Pop</a>"><img src="img/settings.png"></a>
```

Comment: sorry... what do you mean....

Comment: Can you show what does not work and what you mean by a data tag with quites?

Comment: I cannot put the tag ('code') inside the href data tag. As I cannot use both ' and " inside the tag.

Comment: Show what you mean....what is the "invalid" code

Comment: The code becomes invalid and does not work when I put the link inside the data-content=" " tag I just put in the question on the bottom. If I put " around all of it, the href and chat it doesn't read the script. It just opens the chat page as it would by a default link.

Comment: what framework are you using bootstrap??

Comment: I'm not using Bootstrap or anything like that. The script just doesn't work if they're all " or '. The ('chat') needs to have different quotation marks around it. Than the rest.

Comment: So if you have " inside, it will need to be escaped to `@quot;` or better yet, do not use inline events.

Comment: I'm still fairly new to JavaScript. Can I "convert" the script and use the document.getElementById("id") to avoid inline events?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `"` in the attribute value

```
<a href="#" class="emotes show-pop btn btn-default top" data-title="Settings" data-content="<a href=&quot;chat&quot; onclick=&quot;return popitup('chat')&quot;>Pop</a>"><img src="img/settings.png"></a>
```

Comment: Using this links me to website/"chat"

Answer (score 0):

After referring this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699276/can-data-attribute-contain-html-tags) post, I tried to reproduce your code as below. Thing you missed is that you need to escape '<','>' and '"'

```
<a href="chat" onclick="return popitup('chat')">Pop</a>

<script>
function popitup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,height=600,width=330');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}
</script>

<a href="#" class="emotes show-pop btn btn-default top" data-title="Settings" data-content='&lt;a href=&quot;chat&quot; onclick=&quot;return popitup("chat")&quot;&gt;Pop&lt;/a&gt;'>
    <img src="img/settings.png">
 </a>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. With this, it loads the page /chat but still as a normal link, it breaks the script. Should I try to make a JavaScript or find one to getElementById instead? I've tried a bunch of things now - but it's still not popping up, just a regular link.

Comment: Try adding "_blank" in window.open. window.open(url,'name','toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,height=600,width=330', '_blank');

Comment: Still opens in the same window. So I guess it's the JavaScript not working.