# Are html tags inside directive attribute valid in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I was doing code review and found custom directive with html tags inside attribute:

```
<form-field help="Use <b>foo</b> option to blah blah"></form-field>
```

I find it very unusual, and thought that it will not work in older browsers. But when I and author of this code checked - it turned out that it works in every version of IE we had (10+) and in Chrome/FF without any troubles.

Moreover I checked it in W3C validator (validator.w3.org) and it looks like HTML allows to have unescaped tags inside attributes. This SO answers [Can data-* attribute contain HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699276/can-data-attribute-contain-html-tags) confirms that too.

So my question is: Can this make troubles when used with AngularJS? Will this behavior change in Angular 2.0? And finally is this accepted usage of attributes?

I personally would like something like this:

```
<form-field>
  <help>
   Use <b>foo</b> option to blah blah
  </help>
</form-fild>
```

Comment: Even if it works, it's ugly. Why not use transclude instead?

Comment: Good point @JBNizet but this directive already uses transclude for main content (form control e.g. input), and additionally in some cases it must also display help message - since my college used attribute for help message content

Comment: You can have several transcludes in angular 1.5.

Comment: @JBNizet - Thanks I will check it out, this may be simple and elegant solution to this problem

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that with ng-bind-html directive. Take a look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: I asked about *usage* of html tags in AngularJS directive attribute and it's consequences not how to display html in Angular