# Angular throwing validation error when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i always get error in my dropdown asking me to "Please select a value from the list"  no matter what i select.  It works, when i replace the job id from guid to integers. but fails with GUID. Any thoughts?

This is my HTML that works

```
<select class="form-control ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-validselected" name="job_id" id="job_id" data-ng-model="formJobApplyData.job_id" data-ng-options="job.JobTitle for job in jobList track by job.JobId" data-validate-selected="">
   <option value="0" selected="selected" label="Select a Job from the List">Select a Job from the List</option>  
   <option value="1" label="Job1">JOB 1 </option>
   <option value="2" label="Job2">Job 2</option>
 </select>

<div data-ng-messages="jobForm.job_id.$error" data-ng-show="jobForm.job_id.$invalid &amp;&amp; (jobForm.$touched || jobForm.$dirty)" class="form-message ng-active">
                    <!-- ngMessage: validselected --><p data-ng-message="validselected" class="ng-scope">
                        You must select a job from the list
</p>
</div>
```

but if replace the select with below - it fails

```
<select class="form-control ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-validselected" name="job_id" id="job_id" data-ng-model="formJobApplyData.job_id" data-ng-options="job.JobTitle for job in jobList track by job.JobId" data-validate-selected="">
   <option value="0" selected="selected" label="Select a Job from the List">Select a Job from the List</option>
   <option value="{19232633-2bd1-4f6c-8ce7-81d428ee0a2b}" label="Job1">JOB 1 </option>
   <option value="{09712b88-bc6c-4e51-9385-bb529e205724}" label="Job2">Job 2</option>
 </select>
```

in the Value field i tried to replace `"{ 09712b88-bc6c-4e51-9385-bb529e205724}"` with `"09712b88bc6c4e519385bb529e205724"` . Same result.

Guys - What am i missing?

Comment: Any suggestion ???

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing second option. You have this in both snippets:

```
JOB 1/option>
```

Don't know if that's your actual code but if it is that is a problem.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4699314/3386085) about what is acceptable inside html element's attribute. You should be able to have almost anything in there.

Comment: Thanks  @onzinsky  that was only a typo. since i copy pasted here.. it got carried over. i have updated the quesiton.