# Escaping quotes in html CSS parameter doesn't work as planned

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a hyperref like this:

```
<a class="link-efekt-viri" data-hover="LPC4088 <span class="icon"></class>" href="..." target="_blank">LPC4088 <span class="icon"></span></a>
```

But double quotes for `data-hover` CSS parameter are troubling me, because they won't apply class `icon` which sets `font-family: icon-font;` where font family is set like this:

```
@font-face {font-family: "icon-font"; src: url(../fonts/fontawesome.ttf);}
```

I tried to escape the double quotes by using `&quot;` like this:

```
<a class="link-efekt-viri" data-hover="LPC4088 <span class=&quot;icon&quot;></class>" href="..." target="_blank">LPC4088 <span class="icon"></span></a>
```

but int won't work like planned. I get something like this:

[image]

I need `data-hover` parameter because it is used for correct animation of the icon.

Comment: Can you not use single quotes?

Comment: Where exactly did you mean? There are multiple places that I could use them. I tried `data-hover='LPC4088 <span>...</span>` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a functional example somewhere?

Comment: Not yet as it would be quite large. I decided to wait a bit if anyone knows the solution without MWE. If I understand the problem must lie in escaping the double quotes somehow plus applying a style... Maybee some PHP (although I avoid it) would work IDK.

Comment: Have you tried escaping all of the characters? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699276/can-data-attribute-contain-html-tags

Comment: Using all escape characters like @Ouroborus sugested doesn't apply the CSS. It just renders like `LPC4088 <span class="icon"></span>` without applying class `icon` to my icon ``.

Comment: @71GA If you're embedding CSS in HTML (e.g.: `style` attribute) you need to use HTML escaping. If you need to escape characters as part of CSS (as in `content`), there's a different encoding that's used. You can't use HTML in CSS and expect it to work (as in `content:"<span>text</span>"`). `data-hover` doesn't do anything on it's own; it needs supporting Javascript. If your `data-hover` content is rendering as raw text, the supporting Javascript is expecting only text and is treating it like text.

Comment: Just a comment. It's easy to use single quotes within double quotes. You should separate data from the DOM. Your HTML tags should be valid and match, as well.

Comment: This question is missing a lot of information - such as what is actually being DONE with the contents of that attribute. How is it being used? I suspect you're trying to show the contents using CSS, if that's the case then HTML simply won't work, it's not possible. You would need JavaScript to parse the HTML and insert it into the DOM.

Comment: Thank you @Nick. This is what I needed. So it can't be done and I will have to try diferent approach.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using single quotes on the `class='icon'` inside the `span` tags?

```
<a class="link-efekt-viri" data-hover="LPC4088 <span class='icon'></span>" href="..." target="_blank">LPC4088 <span class='icon'></span></a>
```

(Note: You closed the first `span`tag with a `</class>` tag instead of `</span>` which I also changed here.)