# Semantic-UI "no javascript" Tooltips : Can we put part of the text in bold?

Tags: jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I'm using "no javascript" Tooltips (see "Tooltip" here: https://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#tooltip ).

What's the quickest way to put part of the text in bold?

I tried this but it does not work:

```
<div class="ui button" data-tooltip="Add users to your <strong>feed</strong>" data-position="top left">
  Top Left
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" integrity="sha256-/Z28yXtfBv/6/alw+yZuODgTbKZm86IKbPE/5kjO/xY=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js" integrity="sha256-Bhi6GMQ/72uYZcJXCJ2LToOIcN3+Cx47AZnq/Bw1f7A=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<span>
<div class="ui button" data-tooltip="Add users to your <strong>feed</strong>" data-position="bottom left">
      Bottom Left
    </div> </span>
```

Comment: You should post all your current code so that we can recreate your issue.

Comment: @ScottBrown Please run the snippet attached!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can data-\* attribute contain HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699276/can-data-attribute-contain-html-tags)

Comment: It looks like the answer is no, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699276/can-data-attribute-contain-html-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at https://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#tooltip under **Flow** you can use that to give an identical appearance but different approach it might work for you.

I believe the tool-tip will render it as pure text and will not allow html values.

hope this helps, you can adapt it to your needs and remove columns you don't need and apply other styles etc..

```
<div class="ui button">Show flowing popup</div>
<div class="ui flowing popup top left transition hidden">
  <div class="ui three column divided center aligned grid">
    <div class="column">
      <h4 class="ui header">Basic Plan</h4>
      <p><b>2</b> projects, $10 a month</p>
      <div class="ui button">Choose</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h4 class="ui header">Business Plan</h4>
      <p><b>5</b> projects, $20 a month</p>
      <div class="ui button">Choose</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h4 class="ui header">Premium Plan</h4>
      <p><b>8</b> projects, $25 a month</p>
      <div class="ui button">Choose</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok! thanks!  Do I need to use some Javascript for this?  Or only the HTML?

Comment: just apply the semantic UI styles + js files as you have done in your posted example.