# Why does PHP give me different results for my variable?

Tags: php, html

I can no longer understand the behavior of PHP.

I have a `for` loop that shows me a button on each line and that allows me to open a modal to display variable parameters:

```
<?php $postes = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM candidate_postes;');
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($postes); $i++){
       $var[$i] = ucfirst(strftime('%d %B %Y',strtotime($postes[$i]['date_time_publication'])));
?>    
     <tr>
                                                               
        <td> <?php echo $postes[$i]['id']; ?> </td> 

        <td><a class='text-gray-600 text-hover-primary mb-1'><?php echo $postes[$i]['title']; ?></a></td>
        
        <td><a class='text-gray-600 text-hover-primary mb-1'><?php echo $postes[$i]['candidate_numbers']; ?></a></td>
                                                                                                                
        <td><?php echo $var[$i]; ?></td>
                                                                                                               
        <td class="text-end">                                                                
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-light btn-active-light-primary" data-menu-trigger="click">Actions 
                                                                        
               <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-5 m-0">
                                                                            
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none">                                                          
                   <path d="M11.4343 12.7344L7.25 8.55005C6.83579 8.13583 6.16421 8.13584 5.75 8.55005C5.33579 8.96426 5.33579 9.63583 5.75 10.05L11.2929 15.5929C11.6834 15.9835 12.3166 15.9835 12.7071 15.5929L18.25 10.05C18.6642 9.63584 18.6642 8.96426 18.25 8.55005C17.8358 8.13584 17.1642 8.13584 16.75 8.55005L12.5657 12.7344C12.2533 13.0468 11.7467 13.0468 11.4343 12.7344Z" fill="currentColor" />                                                       
                  </svg>
                                                                        
               </span>
                                                                    
           </a>
                                                                    
           <div class="menu menu-sub menu-sub-dropdown menu-column menu-rounded menu-gray-600 menu-state-bg-light-primary fw-bold fs-7 w-125px py-4" data-menu="true">
                                                                        
                <div class="menu-item px-3">
                                                                             
                   <a href="#" class="menu-link px-3"
                                                                                
                                                                             
                      data-id="<?php echo $postes[$i]['id']; ?>"    
                                                                             
                      data-postetitle="<?php echo $postes[$i]['poste']; ?>"    
                                                                             
                      data-postedesc="<?php echo $postes[$i]['desc']; ?>" 
                                                                             
                      data-postecontent="<?php echo $postes[$i]['content']; ?>" 
                                                                             
                      data-postenumber="<?php echo $postes[$i]['candidate_numbers']; ?>"
                                                                                
                                                                             
                      onclick="
                                                                                      
             $('#dataid').val(id);                                                             
                 
             $('#datatitle').text($(this).data('postetitle'));
                                                                                      
             $('#datatitlebis').text($(this).data('postetitle'));
                                                                                      
           $('#datatitlethird').text($(this).data('postetitle'));
                                                                                      
             $('#datadesc').text($(this).data('postedesc'));
                                                                                      
            $('#datacontent').text($(this).data('postecontent'));
                                                                                      
    $('#datacandidatesnumber').text($(this).data('postenumber'));
                                                                                      
            $('#modal_candidate_novalidate').modal('show');
                                                                                      
            $('#dataid').val($(this).data('id'));
                                                                            
             ">Candidater</a>
                                                                        
            </div>
                                                                   
         </div>
                                                                
      </td>
   </tr>
                                                        
<?php } ?>
```

In the modal, I retrieve these parameters as a variable:

```
<?php $datatitle = '<span id="datatitle"/>'; echo $datatitle; ?>
```

So far so good.
However, I have a BBCODE stored in my database that I would like to display correctly using the code below:

```
    <div class="fv-row mb-10">
        <label class="col-lg-8 fw-bold text-muted">A propos du rôle :</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8 fv-row">
            <span class="fw-bold text-gray-800 fs-6">
            <?php
                $datacontent = '<span id="datacontent"/>';
                require_once "../../libs/bbcode/SBBCodeParser.php";
                $parser = new \SBBCodeParser\Node_Container_Document();
                echo $parser->parse($datacontent)
                ->detect_links()
                ->get_html(); 
       ?>
             </span>
         </div>
      </div>
```

The problem is that when I load my page, it is not the content of my database that appears, but only `<span id="datacontent"/>`.

[datacontent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYqlE.png)

I can’t understand the behavior of PHP, because when I simply echo my variable, it’s the non-parser code that is displayed.

Does anyone have an explanation and a solution to this phenomenon?

Comment: So to confirm, all the other spans in the modal are being populated with javascript?

Comment: Absolutely, they are filled with <?php $datatitle = '<span id="datatitle"/>'; echo $datatitle; ?> for exemple and that's work

Comment: OK I just had another look, the code is doing exactly what you're telling it to do, you are passing `$datacontent` to `$parser`, `$datacontent` is the span. You want to parse the BBCode and replace this: `<?php echo $postes[$i]['content']; ?>`

Comment: Yes that’s exactly it, I’d like to parse <?php echo $postes[$i]['content']; ?>. But I have trouble to understand because when I put echo, in this case it doesn’t show me span but the content not parser...

Comment: I'm having a hard time following you, could you please post the full code instead of small snippets

Comment: Hello, I changed my code for clarity (you will find the full code of the display of the table). What I want to do is recover $posts[$i]['content'] so that I can use it in my modal in order to parse it and display it correctly. So, in my modal, I want to recover the real value of "$positions[$i]['content']" in a variable.

Comment: @JacobMulquin no idea ?

Comment: I think you need to replace `data-postecontent="<?php echo $postes[$i]['content']; ?>"` with `data-postecontent="<?php echo $parser->parse($postes[$i]['content'])->detect_links()->get_html(); ?>"`

Comment: @JacobMulquin So it works, it gives me the parse of $postes[$i]['content'] in data-postecontent but on the other hand it does this: [Image](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2022/30/5/1659094022-capture-d-ecran-2022-07-29-a-13-26-57.png)

Comment: Two ideas I can think of why that's happening, are there lots of "<br>"s being generated in the parse? Or a CSS issue?

Comment: @JacobMulquin, here is what is displayed in data-postecontent :  [Image](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2022/30/5/1659129192-capture-d-ecran-2022-07-29-a-23-13-08.png)

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4699388/1427345